# OPENSSL RSA public key reading from mem

Tags: openssl

I have some problem while trying to load my public key from mem.
before I was using PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY to load key from disk. but since this will make Cracker get my public key way too easy. I want to load it from a CString Instead of a file.
and I was trying to do it like this:

```
    CString csPubKey = 
    L"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"
    L"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC/g+aYSWhuJc4J30n5U5iC9cwr"
    L"N7Su2NeO/EwubqjypfWY8W9B+lfNk9q2CoTyb5LtZI19rLCY8yrX1vIKLMRzHNri"
    L"LSXNAk+tWsnf7qupJep6mn5EeAPV7AG1p1i7txvoWBf289YI8wlGsr0DMUIfQxAW"
    L"hSwlRYqJ64wRx7sXMQIDAQAB"
    L"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

BIO *bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(CW2A(csPubKey.GetBuffer()),csPubKey.GetLength());


if(PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bio,&pRSAPublicKey, 0, 0) == NULL)
{
    CStringA err = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
    //assert(false);
    return "";
}
```

and I get error error:0906D06C:lib(9):func(109):reason(108) when PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY.
on Google it says this is about no start line.  anyone knows what I did wrong?

Comment: I've read elsewhere on SO that you need `\n` at the end of each line... but if that were the problem, Using `CStringA` wouldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use CStringA and fixed the problem, I dunno why CW2A doesn't work as the same.

Answer (score 0):

> PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY... on Google it says this is about no start line.

Its a wide string. Convert it to a narrow string first.

You should also release the buffer from `sPubKey.GetBuffer()`.

---

> ... since this will make Cracker get my public key way too easy.

Its a public key. Its meant to be freely distributed.

Comment: I think I have already convert it at CW2A(csPubKey.GetBuffer() ?

Comment: I think narrow string is same as  Ansi  so CW2A works for this?